# How to stop enter character getting stuck in buffer? C

Tags: c, stdin, stdio, getchar

So in the following bit of code I'm reading an option from the user to then decide whether to perform a given action:

```
printf("Do you want to execute %s: ", exe);

char input = getchar();

if (input == 'y') {
    return execute(exe);
} return 0;
```

The problem I'm having is that after the line `char input = getchar()` a character (I'm assuming an enter key or newline) gets stuck in `stdin`, and a future call to `fgets()` (reading from `stdin`) from my `execute()` function therefore eats up this stuck character and doesn't prompt the user for the required input.

Now I can define the following function to 'eat' any stray characters for me if called before calling `execute()`...

```
void iflush() {
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        continue;
    }
}
```

... and this solves the problem. But I'm left wondering why this is happening in the first place? Is there a more 'proper' way of getting a `char` from `stdin` without causing this stray character which then messes up my other methods? I'm very new to C and am keen to be sure I'm learning good habits.

It seems odd that I have to add a helper method, even if simple, to prevent errors in my program just from recording some user input. I've tried using `fgetc()` also but same problem.

Comment: Did you try `fflush(stdin);` after the statement where you call `getchar()`?

Comment: yeah that didn't do anything

Comment: @VHS You know it is a really bad advice? `fflush(stdin);` is invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: @VHS: Please read [Using `fflush(stdin)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin) for a more nuanced story about `fflush(stdin)` — it is defined on Windows when using the Microsoft C run time libraries, but it is otherwise not portable.

Comment: It is definitively not trivial to parse input (data in general), so writing such an helper (yours is broken as good chars are lost, return them when input is correct) is very common.

Comment: Note: Better to use `int input = getchar();` rather than `char input = getchar();`, just like code did in `iflush()`.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm left wondering why this is happening in the first place?

It's because when you can characters with `%c` (or `fgetc()`), it doesn't ignore ay of the whitespaces in the input stream.
Some format specifiers, for example `%d`, ignore any whitespaces left in the input stream. So, it's not a problem. But `%c` doesn't ignore it.
Hence, you typically use those "eat" functions.

Think if you are scanning a whitespace character (such as *space*, newline, etc), how'd you able to scan it using `scanf()`?
Obviously, there are different and *better* ways such as using `fgets()`.

> I'm very new to C and am keen to be sure I'm learning good habits.

My suggestion is to avoid `scanf()` completely. Instead use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) to read a line and then you can parse that line using [`sscanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html). Please read: [Why does everyone say not to use scanf? What should I use instead?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)

One thing to be aware about `fgets()` is if you input buffer has enough space, then it'll read the newline character as well,
which you would want to avoid in most user inputs. So, you need to check if the last character is a newline and then remove it.

You can achieve it using `strcspn()` function such as:

```
char line[256];
if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) == NULL) {
    /* handle failure */
}
line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0; /* remove the newline char if present */
```

If you are mainly interested in reading just one char, then an array 3 chars would be sufficient. Still using a larger buffer doesn't hurt:

```
char line[256];
char ch;
if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) == NULL) {
    /* handle failure */
}
if (sscanf(line, "%c", &ch) != 1) {
    /* handle failure */        
}
/* Now you can use 'ch' to check if it's 'y' */
```

Comment: Very nice except "reading just one char, then an array 2 chars would be sufficient".   Usually to read one `char`, folks don't count the `\n`. Likely need at least 3 for the: character, line-feed and null character.  Recommend buffer sizes twice what you think the maximum should be.  256 is nice for user input.

Comment: `fgets()` would only store the `\n` if there's no room in the buffer. So, 2 is sufficient: 1 char and the zero byte. So when reading one char (even if it's a newline) 2 byte buffer size is good enough.

Comment: True, yet the `'\n'` remains in `stdin` for the next input operation - something OP appears to want to avoid should a user under `"y\n"` to read just "one" character.  If code needs to read one character at a time including `'\n'`, just use `fgetc()` - this handles reading the null character, which is problematic with  `fgets()`.

Comment: I have modified it slightly in order to handle that. Thanks.

Comment: Using strcspn () like that is bad advice as it is possible to read lines with no trailing newline character.

Comment: @BjornA. It's not. If there's no trailing newline, it'll simply overwrite the null byte.

Comment: Usr: what happens  if the input is a single char or a line longer than the buffer?

Comment: @usr, forget my bad comment.